# How to track Facebook messenger bot text messages

Tags: php, facebook-messenger-bot

I am building a Facebook messenger bot using PHP, I have gotten to  a stage and am confused. 
I asked a question and expecting an answer, this works but want a condition such that when answer is provided to that particular question, another question shows.

My problem is tracking the exact questions. I can't do it since I supposed I can't use text and payload. Please how I do this?

```
$senderId = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id']; 
$messageText = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text']; 
if ($messageText == "origin"){
    $output = "Please enter your phone number";
    $response = [
        'recipient' => ['id' => $senderId],
        'message' => ['text' => $output]
    ];
} //How to specify other conditions 
$ch = curl_init($url);
/* curl setting to send a json post data */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($response));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
if ($message != "") {
    curl_exec($ch); // user will get the message
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: You can keep last user message in a database or session using a Page-Scope user ID as key.